# Problem in my Proof (If $\hat{f}=0$ then $f=0$) (pass derivative from integral)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I need idea about my problem but if you have another type proof please give a hint not a whole solution.

> **Problem**: Let 
>   $f\in L^{2}[-1,1], \; \hat{f}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$
>   and
>   $Q_{c}\hat{f}=0.$
>   i.e.
>   $\int_{-c}^{c}f(x)e^{-2\pi ixt}dx=0.$
>   Prove that 
>   $f=0.$

What I have done:

> the overall idea is to use Plancherel theorem, i.e. 
>   $\Vert f\Vert_{2}=\Vert \hat{f}\Vert_{2}.$
>   I want to prove that 
>   $\hat{f}(t)=0$
>   for all $t.$
>   For this, I see that 
>   $\vert\hat{f}(t)\vert\leq \int_{-1}^{1}\vert f(x)\vert dx<\infty.$
>   Now, I want to prove that 
>   $\hat{f}(t)$
>   is analytic so that I can use Liouville theorem and proving that $\hat{f}=0.$

For the analyticity, I see that 
$e^{2\pi ixt}$
is analytic. But I can't use Leibniz integral rule because of my integrand ($f(x)e^{-2\pi ixt}$) in 
$\hat{f}$
is not necessarily continuous.